# Writing a shell emulator in C for Operating Systems: Shell not staying active after multiple commands given

Tags: c, shell, command-line, operating-system

These are the requirements:

1. Can execute a command with the accompanying arguments.
2. Recognize multiple pipe requests and handle them.
3. Recognize redirection requests and handle them.
4. Type "exit" to quit the shhh shell.

Here are my issue:

Whenever I do more than one command (with command1 | command2), my shell terminates after executing the commands given, instead of waiting for another command line prompt inside my shell. The program is supposed to keep running, and allow a user to enter more commands, until the enter "exit."

```
Code: 
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <unistd.h>
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/stat.h>
        #include <fcntl.h>

    int main() {
        // professor-supplied variables for commands and command parsing
        char *path, *argv[20], buf[80], n, *p;
        int m, status, inword, continu;

        // flags for redirection (note: C does not have type bool; using integer value 0 or 1)
        int inputRedirectFlag, outputRedirectFlag, backgroundJobFlag;
        int numArguments, argIndex, argCount, pipes, openPipesCount, pid, directoryIndex;

        // pipes
        int p1[2], p2[2];

        // index for directory set prior to while(1)
        directoryIndex = 0;

        while (1) {


            inword = 0;
            p = buf;
            m = 0;
            continu = 0;
            numArguments = 0;
            argIndex = 0;
            argCount = 0;
            pipes = 0;
            openPipesCount = 0;
            pid = 0;

            // required containers
            int argumentContainer[20] = { 0 };
            char currentDirectory[80] = { 0 };

            // file variables
            char *outputFile = (char *)0;
            char *inputFile = (char *)0;

            // redirection flags
            inputRedirectFlag = 0;
            outputRedirectFlag = 0;
            backgroundJobFlag = 0;

            // SHELL PROMPT
            printf("\nshhh> ");

            // COMMAND PARSING
            while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu)
            {
                /*************************************************
                 required addition to remediate segmentation fault
                *************************************************/
                 if (n == EOF){
                    exit(0);
                }

                if (n == ' ') {
                    if (inword)
                    {
                        inword = 0;
                        *p++ = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (n == '\n')
                    continu = 0;
                else if (n == '\\' && !inword)
                    continu = 1;
                else {
                    if (!inword)
                    {
                        inword = 1;
                        argv[m++] = p;
                        *p++ = n;
                    }
                    else
                        *p++ = n;
                }
            }

            *p++ = 0;
            argv[m] = 0;

            // capture current working directory
            getcwd(currentDirectory, 80);

            // user wishes to terminate program
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                exit(0);

            // managing input and output redirection and piping
            while (argv[argCount] != 0) {
                if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "<") == 0)
                {
                    inputFile = strdup(argv[argCount + 1]);
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argv[argCount + 1] = 0;
                    inputRedirectFlag = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], ">") == 0)
                {
                    outputFile = strdup(argv[argCount + 1]);
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argv[argCount + 1] = 0;
                    outputRedirectFlag = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "&") == 0)
                {
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    backgroundJobFlag = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "|") == 0)
                {
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argumentContainer[pipes + 1] = argCount + 1;
                    pipes++;
                }
                else
                    argumentContainer[argCount] = argCount;

                ++argCount;
            }

            // execute commands
            for (int i = 0; i <= pipes; ++i) {
                // pipe and track piping
                if (i < pipes) {
                    pipe(p1);
                    ++openPipesCount;
                }

                /*************************************
                 SWITCH STATEMENT FOR PIPE EXECUTION
                *************************************/

                /*******************************************************
                 Using file flags:
                 O_CREAT: creates file if file does not already exist
                 O_RDONLY: Access mode for file (read only)
                 00700(Mode): read/write/execute permission granted
                 From: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html
                ********************************************************/

                // parent forks child for every exec()
                switch (pid = fork()) {
                    case -1: // process error
                            perror("fork failed");
                            break;

                    case 0: // child process
                            if ((i == 0) && (inputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                                int input = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
                                if (input == -1) {
                                printf("Input file failed to open\n");
                                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            close(0);
                            dup(input);
                            close(input);
                            }
                            else if ((i == pipes) && (outputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                                int output = open(outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 00700);
                                if (output < 0) {
                                printf("Output file failed to open\n");
                                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            close(1);
                            dup(output);
                            close(output);
                        }
                        // EXECUTE COMMAND
                        execvp(argv[argumentContainer[argIndex]], &argv[argumentContainer[argIndex]]);
                        break;

                    default: // parent process
                            if (openPipesCount > 0) {
                                close(p2[0]);
                                close(p2[1]);
                            }
                            p2[0] = p1[0];
                            p2[1] = p1[1];
                            break;
                }
                /*************************************
                 END SWITCH STATEMENT FOR PIPE EXECUTION
                 *************************************/

                // if job is not a run-in-background process, wait for process to complete
                if (backgroundJobFlag == 0)
                    wait((int *)0);
            }

            // user wishes to terminate program
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                exit(0);

            // clear all executed commands
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                argv[i] = 0;

            wait(&status);
        }
    }
```

First update/change. Multiple commands are working, but now my file redirection (for input) is not working, among other issues:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    //#include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    #ifndef READ
    #define READ 0
    #endif

    #ifndef WRITE
    #define WRITE 1
    #endif

    int main() {
        // professor-supplied variables for commands and command parsing
        char *path, *argv[20], buf[80], n, *p;
        int m, status, inword, continu;
        int inputRedirectFlag, outputRedirectFlag, backgroundJobFlag;
        int numArguments, argIndex, argCount, activeCommands, openPipesCount;
        pid_t pid;
        int directoryIndex, commandArchiveIndex;
        int oldFileDescriptor[2], newFileDescriptor[2];
        directoryIndex = 0;

        while (1) {
            inword = 0;
            p = buf;
            m = 0;
            continu = 0;
            numArguments = 0;
            argIndex = 0;
            argCount = 0;
            activeCommands = 0;
            openPipesCount = 0;
            pid = 0;
            path = (char*)0;

            // required containers
            int argumentContainer[20] = { 0 };
            char currentDirectory[80] = { 0 };

            // archive of all commands
            char *commandArchive[20] = { 0 };

            // redirection flags
            inputRedirectFlag = 0;
            outputRedirectFlag = 0;

            backgroundJobFlag = 0;

            // SHELL PROMPT
            printf("\nshhh> ");

            // COMMAND PARSING
            while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu)
            {
                if (n == ' ') {
                    if (inword)
                    {
                        inword = 0;
                        *p++ = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (n == '\n')
                    continu = 0;
                else if (n == '\\' && !inword)
                    continu = 1;
                else {
                    if (!inword)
                    {
                        inword = 1;
                        argv[m++] = p;
                        *p++ = n;
                    }
                    else
                        *p++ = n;
                }
            }

            *p++ = 0;
            argv[m] = 0;

            // capture all commands in command archive
            while (argv[argIndex] != 0)
            {
                commandArchive[numArguments] = strdup(argv[argIndex]);
                numArguments++;
                ++argIndex;
            }

            // capture current working directory
            getcwd(currentDirectory, 80);

            // user wishes to terminate program
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                exit(0);

            /*************************
             MANAGE BUILT-IN FUNCTIONS
             **************************/
            // user command is "cd"
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "cd") == 0) {
                if (strcmp(argv[1], ".") == 0){ // this should do nothing as a command
                    // *path = ???
                    break;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[1], "..") == 0) { // this should move user up one directory
                    // *path = ???
                     // NEED TO PASS PATH HERE!
                    chdir(currentDirectory);
                }
                else {
                    while (argv[directoryIndex] != 0) {
                        getcwd(currentDirectory, 80);
                        // *path = ???
                        // NEED TO PASS PATH HERE!
                        chdir(argv[directoryIndex]);
                        ++directoryIndex;
                    }
                }
            }

            /********************************************
             MANAGE REDIRECTION AND BACKGROUND PROCESSING
            ********************************************/
            while (argv[argCount] != 0) {
                if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "|") == 0) {
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argumentContainer[activeCommands + 1] = argCount + 1;
                    ++activeCommands;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "<") == 0) {
                    path = strdup(argv[argCount + 1]);
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argv[argCount + 1] = 0;
                    inputRedirectFlag = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], ">") == 0) {
                    path = strdup(argv[argCount + 1]);
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    argv[argCount + 1] = 0;
                    outputRedirectFlag = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(argv[argCount], "&") == 0) {
                    argv[argCount] = 0;
                    backgroundJobFlag = 1;
                }
                else {
                    argumentContainer[argCount] = argCount;
                }

                ++argCount;
            }

            // execute commands
            for (int pipeIndex = 0; pipeIndex <= activeCommands; ++pipeIndex) {
                if (pipeIndex < activeCommands) { // if user has entered multiple commands with '|'
                    pipe(oldFileDescriptor);
                    pipe(newFileDescriptor);
                    ++openPipesCount;
                }

                /*************************************
                 SWITCH STATEMENT FOR PIPE EXECUTION
                 *************************************/

                // capture current path
                //path = getenv("PATH");

                /*******************************************************
                 Using file flags:
                 O_CREAT: creates file if file does not already exist
                 O_RDONLY: Access mode for file (read only)
                 0600(Mode): owner can read/write
                ddddddddddddd
                 ********************************************************/

                // parent forks child for every exec()
                switch (pid = fork()) {
                    case -1: // process error
                        perror("fork failed");
                        break;

                    case 0: // child process

                        /****************************************************
                         HAVE CHILD PROCESS MANAGE REDIRECTION
                         ****************************************************/
                        if ((pipeIndex == 0) && (inputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                            int input = open(path, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
                            if (input == -1) {
                                printf("Input file failed to open\n");
                                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            //close(READ);
                            //dup(input);
                            //close(input);
                            dup2(input, READ);
                            close(input);
                        }
                        else if ((pipeIndex == activeCommands) && (outputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                            int output = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
                            if (output < 0) {
                                printf("Output file failed to open\n");
                                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            //close(WRITE);
                            //dup(output);
                            //close(output);
                            dup2(output, WRITE);
                            close(output);
                        }
                        /****************************************************
                         REDIRECTION (IF APPLICABLE) EXECUTED BY CHILD PROCESS
                         ****************************************************/

                        /*******************************************************************************
                         CHILD EXECUTES COMMAND:
                         *******************************************************************************/
                        execvp(argv[argumentContainer[pipeIndex]], &argv[argumentContainer[pipeIndex]]);
                        /*******************************************************************************
                         EXECUTION COMPLETE
                         *******************************************************************************/
                        break;

                    default: // parent process
                        if (openPipesCount > 0) { // previous command
                            //close(READ);
                            //dup(newFileDescriptor[READ]);
                            close(newFileDescriptor[READ]);
                            close(newFileDescriptor[WRITE]);
                        }

                        if (openPipesCount < activeCommands) { // more commands need to be executed
                            close(newFileDescriptor[READ]);
                            dup(newFileDescriptor[WRITE]);
                            close(newFileDescriptor[WRITE]);
                        }

                        oldFileDescriptor[READ] = newFileDescriptor[READ];
                        oldFileDescriptor[WRITE] = newFileDescriptor[WRITE];
                        break;
                }
                /***************************************
                 END SWITCH STATEMENT FOR PIPE EXECUTION
                 **************************************/

                // if job is not a run-in-background process, wait for process to complete
                if (backgroundJobFlag == 0)
                    wait((int *)0);
            }

            // user wishes to terminate program
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
                exit(0);

            // clear all executed commands
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                argv[i] = 0;

            wait(&status);
        }
    }
```

I know I'm probably doing something wrong with argumentContainer[] or my piping. I'm just lost.

UPDATED VERSION (update 2):

I made quite a few changes after discussing my code with my professor. It's nearly working. I'm able to pipe multiple commands, etc. However, "wc" seems to freeze and wait for an EOF (ctrl+d), and cd isn't changing directories. Wonder if I need to make a special case/code for "cd."

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifndef READ
#define READ 0
#endif

#ifndef WRITE
#define WRITE 1
#endif

int main() {
    /* professor-supplied variables for commands and command parsing */
    char *path, *argv[20], buf[80], n, *p;
    int m, status, inword, continu;

    /* flags for redirection (note: C does not have type bool; using integer value 0 or 1) */
    int inputRedirectFlag, outputRedirectFlag;

    /* variables for piping */
    int count, pipes;
    pid_t pid;

    /* pipes */
    int l_pipe[2], r_pipe[2];

    while (1) {
        inword = m = continu = count = pipes = pid = 0;
        p = buf;

        /* required container for handling arguments */
        int argumentContainer[20] = { 0 };

        /* redirection flags */
        inputRedirectFlag = 0;
        outputRedirectFlag = 0;

        /* shell prompt */
        printf("\nshhh> ");

        /* command parsing */
        while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu)
        {
            if (n == ' ') {
                if (inword)
                {
                    inword = 0;
                    *p++ = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (n == '\n')
                continu = 0;
            else if (n == '\\' && !inword)
                continu = 1;
            else {
                if (!inword)
                {
                    inword = 1;
                    argv[m++] = p;
                    *p++ = n;
                }
                else
                    *p++ = n;
            }
        } /* end of command parsing */

        *p++ = 0;
        argv[m] = 0;

        /* user wishes to terminate program */
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
            exit(0);

        /* manage redirection */
        while (argv[count] != 0) {
            if (strcmp(argv[count], "|") == 0) {
                argv[count] = 0;
                argumentContainer[pipes + 1] = count + 1;
                ++pipes;
            }
            else if (strcmp(argv[count], "<") == 0) {
                path = strdup(argv[count + 1]); /* copy string argument (file string) */
                argv[count] = 0;
                argv[count + 1] = 0;
                inputRedirectFlag = 1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(argv[count], ">") == 0) {
                path = strdup(argv[count + 1]); /* copy string argument (file string) */
                argv[count] = 0;
                argv[count + 1] = 0;
                outputRedirectFlag = 1;
            }
            else {
                argumentContainer[count] = count;
            }

            ++count;
        } /* end of redirection management */

        /* execute commands */
        for (int index = 0; index <= pipes; ++index) {
            if (index < pipes) { /* if user has entered multiple commands with '|' */
                pipe(r_pipe); /* no pipe(l_pipe); r_pipe becomes next child's l_pipe */
            }

            /*************************************************************************
             FILE FLAG AND FILE MODE DESCRIPTION AND DETAILS:
             *************************************************************************
             Using file flags:
             O_CREAT: creates file if file does not already exist
             O_REDONLY: Acess mode for file (read only)
             O_WRONLY: Access mode for file (write only)
             0600(Mode): owner can read/write
             From:
             http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command
             ************************************************************************
             ***********************************************************************/

            /* switch-statement for command execution */
            switch (pid = fork()) {
                /* fork() error */
                case -1: perror("fork failed");
                         break;

                case 0: /* child process manages redirection and executes */
                       if ((index == 0) && (inputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                           int input = open(path, O_RDONLY , 0600);
                           if (input == -1) {
                               printf("Input file failed to open\n");
                               return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                           }
                           dup2(input, READ);
                           close(input);
                       } /* end of input redirection management */
                       else if ((index == pipes) && (outputRedirectFlag == 1)) {
                           int output = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0600);
                           if (output < 0) {
                               printf("Output file failed to open\n");
                               return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                           }
                           dup2(output, WRITE);
                           close(output);
                       } /* end of output redirection management */

                       /* command executed */
                       execvp(argv[argumentContainer[index]], &argv[argumentContainer[index]]);

                       /* execvp() fails */
                       printf("execution of command failed\n");

                       break;

                default: /* parent process manages the pipes for child process(es) */
                        if (index > 0) {
                            close(l_pipe[READ]);
                            close(l_pipe[WRITE]);
                        }
                        l_pipe[READ] = r_pipe[READ];
                        l_pipe[WRITE] = r_pipe[WRITE];

                        break;
            } /* end of switch-statement for command execution */
        } /* end of loop for all pipes */

        // user wishes to terminate program
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }

        // clear all executed commands
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            argv[i] = 0;
        }

        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to improve your question to increase its future usefulness and the probability of getting answers, consider making [one post per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each.

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you! I went ahead and changed the question to cover only one issue (the shell quitting after executing a command with multiple arguments (use of |). Once that is remedied, I'll tackle the next problem!

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy. You can also make it easier to pinpoint the problem with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, you can exclude 14 lines of `cd` support, 19 lines of redirections, 40 lines of unrelated comments, and still show the exact same problem. Obviously, this is a significant and annoying amount of extra work for you, but if you skip it, you are instead asking whoever answers to do it, and not everyone will take the time.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you. I went ahead and removed some excess comments and the cd handling, but I was reticent to remove the redirections and (relevant?) comments. I'm not sure where the problem is, and I'm concerned it could be in my redirection handling, although it's likely where I'm handling the pipe itself.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, but `n` is a `char`, so you can get either bogus EOF on a valid character or never get EOF at all.  Remember, `getchar()` can return any `char` value treated as an `unsigned char`, plus the EOF condition (which must be negative but need not be `-1`, though it is rarely anything else).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If it's an unsigned char, the value returned will never be negative. I thought of doing "if (n < 0){exit(0);}, but if I'm getting an unsigned return value, that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your pipe handling. You're always closing the pipes in `p2`, but the first time through the loop, they haven't been initialized to anything. Only `p1` has been initialized. One of the values that is by default in `p2` is likely `0`, which is the file descriptor number for `STDIN`. As a result, you're closing the parent program's `STDIN` when you try to close the pipes in `p2` on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Is p1 being initialized via my pipe() call? If so, is it a simple matter of putting pipe(p2) right after I do pipe(p1)? I've tried that. The compiler doesn't complain or anything, but my second command (e.g. "mkdir NAME" in the command "ls | mkdir NAME") is not being executed. I did confirm that something like "mkdir NAME" works if it is the first/only command.

Comment: You've got other problems, as well, so you won't see any immediate effects from this. I'd recommend drawing out the file descriptor table and thinking about what you want your pipes to point to. The issue you're talking about is from the fact that you always pass the same arguments to `execvp`, since `argIndex` never changes. I honestly can't tell you how to change the way you use your pipes, because right now they're completely unused. You never actually swap them in to the child STD FDs, so I'm not sure which you'll want to be creating when.

Comment: I've made significant changes with positive effect, but wc and cd not working. I removed some code for "cd," thinking execvp() would handle it. Looks like I may have been wrong.

Comment: Those are new, unrelated issues, and so should be a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still fairly new to StackOverflow. Doing my best to learn the ropes. Honestly, I didn't know if it was faux pas to ask a new question about the same code, even if the issues were unrelated to my first inquiry. Wasn't sure if I'd get dinged for it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I've got a final, working code where do I post it? Do I make it its own answer, or update my above code? I want to make sure I act within the StackOverflow guidelines and don't get into trouble for doing something I shouldn't.